# I want to split an array of arrays into coresponding arrays using in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parsing, laravel-5

I have an array of arrays carrying data of multiple forms
i wanna split each form's data into a single array so i can store it to DB
currently doing

```
public function storeWBS(Request $request)
    {
        $value = $request->all();
        $formValue = new WorkBreakdownStructure;

        $count = 0;
     $data_array1 = array();
         foreach ($value as $key => $val2) {
            $data_array= $val2;
                    if (is_array($val2)) {
                    array_push($data_array1, $val2);

            }

        }
        dd($value);
        exit;
        $data_array1->save();
}
```

and Getting this result

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "bcK0e9z168ib7rbSZpoRPLWbhx3bRIHq1NqzfNeX"
  "idea_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "wbs_description" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Visit Campus to read about making great videos and more"
    1 => "Visit Campus to read about \r\n"
    2 => "Visit Campus to read about making great"
  ]
  "percentage" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "30"
    1 => "30"
    2 => "40"
  ]
]
```

i want the to get all values of inner array's index 0 to be in one array
i.e,

```
"idea_id" 
      =>  "1"
"wbs_description" 
      => "Visit Campus to read about making great videos and more"
  "percentage" 
      =>  "30"
```

from above i tried to run an inner loop but it'll result with same 3 arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val2) {
$data_array= $val2;
    if (is_array($val2)) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($val2 as $k=>$v) {
            $data_array1[$count][$key] = $v;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```